# Turn background video (ambient video) into a playable video on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I have created an iframe by taking advantage of YouTube's API.

On page load, the ambient video is set to autoplay with no sound. However, on top of the `div` which contains the `iframe`, I have a button.

On this button click, I want the video to reset (start from the beginning) with the YouTube controls and sound on - similar to the one in the hero here: https://www.hugeinc.com/work.

Wondering how I would go about this? Would it involve creating another iframe?

**Not looking to do this as a modal pop-up**

**Code**:

```js
//  Load  IFrame Player API 
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Creating iframe
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'jagIsKF8oVA',
    playerVars: {
      'autoplay': 1,
      'controls': 0,
      'mute': 1,
      'loop': 1,
      'rel': 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

//  Calls function
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  // if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
  //   setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
  //   done = true;
  // }
}

function stopVideo() {
  // player.stopVideo();
}
```

```html
<!-- THIS IS IN home.php-->

<button>Click me</button>

<!-- THIS IS IN hero.php -->
<section id="videoHero" class="hero hero--video">
  <div class="hero__container--teaser">
    <!-- Where the iframe is stored-->
    <div id="player"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Not looking to do this as a modal pop-up. Similar to the functionality here: https://www.hugeinc.com/work (play button on hero is clicked, video resets and plays from the start with controls at the bottom).

Comment: you want to play the video on modal popup?

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara - yeah, the video will autoplay on page load, on the button click, I want the video to pop up in a modal, with all the default YouTube controls (i.e. video will start from the beginning with the options to pause, play etc.)

Comment: Do you have any logic yet revolving around the modal pop-up? Also, when you click the button, should the video play from the same time as the muted video? I.e. muted video auto-plays, reaches 20 seconds or whatever, and someone clicks the button at that time, should the pop-up video then start from the 20 second mark?

Comment: @Martin - What do you mean by logic? as in the HTML structure? If so, I've updated my question to show the structure. And nope, if the ambient video is 20 seconds in and the user clicks the button, I want the video to pop up on a modal, paused from the beginning.

Comment: By logic I mean the general code for the modal pop-up and how it works. And if you want the video to start from the beginning inside the modal, then a super easy fix would be to just use the same iframe inside the modal box with the required tweaks to what you want. I.e. have the API function to set the correct variables so that it is unmuted etc.

Comment: @Martin - Here's a quick demo of the markup and how it functions: https://jsfiddle.net/gwy98mer/

Comment: Good, so you got your modal and everything to work. Now try add the iframe into the modal along with the API function with the desirable *playerVars* for unmuted video etc.

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gwy98mer/3/ I think it's better to use a new iframe. In this jsfiddle I am appending the same iframe while changing the src witch doesn't make sense

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I've had a bit of a design change. I want the video to function like the on the hero of this page: https://www.hugeinc.com/work. Not so much worried about the styling, but notice how when the pink play button is clicked, the video begins from the start and the controls are visible at the bottom

Comment: @evgenifotia sorry, had a bit of a design change, see comment above - appreciate your help though

Comment: these are two different videos the first one continue playing even after clicking on the pink play button, while the other pause when you click on the cross button.

Comment: @evgenifotia yeah, the idea behind my approach will be a single video. Ambient one that plays in the background automatically, and then on button click, start that video again in the start, with controls.

Answer (score 4):

I used another iframe because there is no method to change the controls display you may check https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference for more information or you can do `console.log(player)` and ckeck all the methods.

I used

```
contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
```

to stop the iframe and

```
contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*')
```

to restart it also for this two line of code to work I added `&enablejsapi=1` to the iframe src

also I used the `YouTube Player API` for the muted video so that it will loop whiteout refresh (in case of not using the `YouTube Player API` for the video to loop you need to add to the src of the iframe `playlist=videoId&loop=1` and this will make the iframe refresh when the video end)

I haven't added `showinfo=0` to the muted video because it is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018.
you may check https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo for more info

Lastly the snippet doesn't work . you need to make local html file or delete `sandbox` from the sinppet iframe then click on `Run code snippet` a second time

```js
var modalTeaser = document.getElementById('hero__container--teaser');
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  var videoId = '88xPxULx-II';
  
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframe', {
        videoId: videoId,
        playerVars: {
          'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 0,
          'mute': 1,
          'loop': 1
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.playVideo(); 
  }
}

var video = document.createElement('iframe');
video.className = "ply";
modalTeaser.prepend(video);
video.style.display = 'none';

video.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoId+"?enablejsapi=1";
video.setAttribute('frameborder', "0");
btn.onclick = function() {
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  video.style.display = "block";
  btn.style.display = "none";
  span.style.display = "block";
  video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*')
}

span.onclick = function() {
  iframe.style.display = "block";
  video.style.display = "none";
  btn.style.display = "block";
  span.style.display = "none";
  video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.close{
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.ply{
  z-index: 2 !important;
}
#videoHero {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: calc((544 / 1280) * 100%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)
}

.hero__container--teaser {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.modal{
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Having the following on the iframe moves the iframe out of the div (and visual). Not having them puts
the iframe in the div, but not full width not height of #videoHero*/

#player,
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

#myBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 122;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  z-index: 400;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section id="videoHero" class="hero hero--video">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-               label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  <div id="hero__container--teaser" class="hero__container--teaser">
    <!-- #player is where the iframe is-->
    <div id="iframe" ></div>
  </div>
  <button id="myBtn">Start video</button>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to really place your code here instead of plain text as code